# How to tell if the number is a palindrome or not in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, int, java.util.scanner, palindrome

I am having trouble figuring out if I am correctly doing the formula for figuring out if a number input by the user is a palindrome or not (also I need to use a while loop). Am I doing the math right? When I trying inputting data it just sits there and does nothing. Here is the code:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number you would like to be checked if it is a palindrome:");
int num = input.nextInt();
int rev = num % 10;
int count = 1;
int i = 0;
int originalNum = num;

while(count < 2)
    rev = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    i = i*10 + rev;

    count = count + 1;
if(originalNum == i)
    System.out.println("The number you input is a palindrome.");
else
    System.out.println("The number you input is not a palindrome.");
```

Comment: Java is not Python. You certainly missed a few braces. Currently, the while loop is only executing `rev = num % 10;` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I sounds easier to do something like `Integer.toString(value).equals(new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(value)).reverse.toString())`

Comment: ZouZou I will try it with braces I guess, also I have never programmed in Python before.

Comment: What I want to know is my formula correct (also for some reason nothing is printing out when I input a number).

Comment: Time to learn how to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code.Now, it works.

```
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int rev=0;
        int i = 0;
        int originalNum = num;

        while(num!=0){
            rev = num % 10;
            i = i*10 + rev;
            num = num / 10;
        }

            if(originalNum == i)
                System.out.println("The number you input is a palindrome.");
            else
                System.out.println("The number you input is not a palindrome.");
```

Answer (score 1):

[See examples of palindrome detection at the Rosetta Code website](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Palindrome_detection#Java).

Here is the first one listed (i.e. the "Non-Recursive" solution). You would, of course, have to cast your number to a String first, to use this one:

> ```
> public static boolean pali(String testMe){
>   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(testMe);
>   return testMe.equals(sb.reverse().toString());
> }
> ```